# Scala Child Class Constructor is not being called from Java Parent Class

Tags: java, scala, inheritance

I am not too sure on what I am doing wrong, I have a Java parent class called Player and a Scala child class Character. When I call the Character class, the parent constructor is being called, but the child constructor is not. I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.

Here is the Java Class (Parent):

```
public class Player implements java.io.Serializable {
    public Player(EntityClientPlayerMP player){
       //...
    }
}
```

Here is the Scala Class (Child):

```
class Character(clientPlayer:EntityClientPlayerMP) extends Player(clientPlayer) with Serializable {

  def Character(client:EntityClientPlayerMP) = {
    //...
  }

  def Character(name:String, playerUID:String) = {
    //...
  }

  def Character(name:String) = {
    //...
  }

  def Character() = {
     //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors in Scala work differently than Java.  In particular, they are *not* a `def` with the same name as the class.  There are various places you can [read about it](http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/).

In any case, if you really need alternate constructors, they look like so:

```
class C(name: String) {
  def this(i: Int) = this(i.toString)
}
```

(The reason is that forgetting to properly initialize things in alternate constructors is a significant source of bugs and extra boilerplate.  By forcing everything to go through a single main constructor, syntax is simpler when you only need one constructor, and initialization bugs are less likely.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, this makes sense: "As I mentioned before the class’ body is the primary constructor"